# Spring boot corrupting fonts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, create-react-app

I have an app built on Spring-Boot (1.5.10.RELEASE) and create-react-app. Everything working fine in development (ie running spring-boot via IDE and using `yarn start` to run the web app.)

Problem is when running the production package. Using embedded tomcat and running using the command `java -jar target/build-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Basically getting the following error messages in the browser console

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: <URL>
localhost/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/static/media/icons.af7ae505.woff2
localhost/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/static/media/icons.af7ae505.woff2
localhost/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/static/media/icons.fee66e71.woff
localhost/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/static/media/icons.fee66e71.woff
localhost/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/static/media/icons.b06871f2.ttf
localhost/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/static/media/icons.b06871f2.ttf
localhost/:1 OTS parsing error: Failed to convert WOFF 2.0 font to SFNT
localhost/:1 OTS parsing error: incorrect file size in WOFF header
localhost/:1 OTS parsing error: incorrect entrySelector for table directory
```

This is the snippet from my `pom.xml` that copies the resources from the web app build directory

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-react-resources</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/app/build</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                                <nonFilteredFileExtension>eot</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                                <nonFilteredFileExtension>svg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                                <nonFilteredFileExtension>ttf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                                <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                                <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff2</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                            </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The fonts appear to be copied over to the target area correctly

eg from the web app build directory

```
$ ls -la src/main/app/build/static/media/
total 1020
drwxrwxr-x 2 pram pram   4096 Jun 17 09:44 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 pram pram   4096 Jun 17 09:44 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram  28123 Jun 17 09:44 flags.9c74e172.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram 165742 Jun 17 09:44 icons.674f50d2.eot
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram 444379 Jun 17 09:44 icons.912ec66d.svg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram  77160 Jun 17 09:44 icons.af7ae505.woff2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram 165548 Jun 17 09:44 icons.b06871f2.ttf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram  98024 Jun 17 09:44 icons.fee66e71.woff
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram  23284 Jun 17 09:44 loader-big.a770b679.gif
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram   3744 Jun 17 09:44 rw-widgets.12f0820c.woff
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram   2765 Jun 17 09:44 rw-widgets.792dcd18.svg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram   6408 Jun 17 09:44 rw-widgets.bc7c4a59.eot
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram   6232 Jun 17 09:44 rw-widgets.eceddf47.ttf
```

and from the target

```
$ ls -la target/classes/static/static/media/
total 1020
drwxrwxr-x 2 pram pram   4096 Jun 17 09:44 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 pram pram   4096 Jun 17 09:44 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram  28123 Jun 17 09:44 flags.9c74e172.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram 165742 Jun 17 09:44 icons.674f50d2.eot
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram 444379 Jun 17 09:44 icons.912ec66d.svg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram  77160 Jun 17 09:44 icons.af7ae505.woff2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram 165548 Jun 17 09:44 icons.b06871f2.ttf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram  98024 Jun 17 09:44 icons.fee66e71.woff
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram  23284 Jun 17 09:44 loader-big.a770b679.gif
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram   3744 Jun 17 09:44 rw-widgets.12f0820c.woff
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram   2765 Jun 17 09:44 rw-widgets.792dcd18.svg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram   6408 Jun 17 09:44 rw-widgets.bc7c4a59.eot
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram   6232 Jun 17 09:44 rw-widgets.eceddf47.ttf
```

and within the deployment artifact

```
$ unzip -vl target/build-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep "static/media"
       0  Stored        0   0% 2018-06-17 09:44 00000000  BOOT-INF/classes/static/static/media/
    3744  Defl:N     3681   2% 2018-06-17 09:44 a861d971  BOOT-INF/classes/static/static/media/rw-widgets.12f0820c.woff
  165742  Defl:N    98260  41% 2018-06-17 09:44 ba1d704f  BOOT-INF/classes/static/static/media/icons.674f50d2.eot
    6232  Defl:N     3458  45% 2018-06-17 09:44 130aa154  BOOT-INF/classes/static/static/media/rw-widgets.eceddf47.ttf
   98024  Defl:N    97913   0% 2018-06-17 09:44 e07b3318  BOOT-INF/classes/static/static/media/icons.fee66e71.woff
    6408  Defl:N     3512  45% 2018-06-17 09:44 06efde2c  BOOT-INF/classes/static/static/media/rw-widgets.bc7c4a59.eot
  444379  Defl:N   136041  69% 2018-06-17 09:44 5f3bf1ae  BOOT-INF/classes/static/static/media/icons.912ec66d.svg
   23284  Defl:N     9111  61% 2018-06-17 09:44 254b8443  BOOT-INF/classes/static/static/media/loader-big.a770b679.gif
  165548  Defl:N    98167  41% 2018-06-17 09:44 c544bc5c  BOOT-INF/classes/static/static/media/icons.b06871f2.ttf
   77160  Defl:N    77153   0% 2018-06-17 09:44 5517c3a7  BOOT-INF/classes/static/static/media/icons.af7ae505.woff2
    2765  Defl:N     1186  57% 2018-06-17 09:44 b229e926  BOOT-INF/classes/static/static/media/rw-widgets.792dcd18.svg
   28123  Defl:N    27946   1% 2018-06-17 09:44 fb476e5a  BOOT-INF/classes/static/static/media/flags.9c74e172.png
```

So the files appear to have copied over without any problem - I confirmed that the files are fine by loading them into http://bluejamesbond.github.io/CharacterMap/

Now, if I pick one of the URLs that were displayed in the error messages eg `http://localhost:8080/static/media/icons.af7ae505.woff2`  and directly navigate to that in my browser it downloads. Then checking the file

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 pram pram      139423 Jun 17 10:25 icons.af7ae505.woff2
```

compared to the file in the target area of the build artifact

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pram pram  77160 Jun 17 09:44 icons.af7ae505.woff2
```

The file sizes are different.

The downloaded file (when opened in sublime) displays as

```
774f 4632 0001 0000 0001 2d68 000d 0000
0002 efbf bdef bfbd 0001 2d0e 0004 01ef
bfbd 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 3f46 4654 4d1c 1a20 0660
00ef bfbd 7211 080a efbf bdef bfbd 28ef
bfbd efbf bd58 0136 0224 03ef bfbd 700b
efbf bd10 0004 2005 efbf bd06 07ef bfbd
755b 5209 7247 61ef bfbd efbf bdef bfbd
2aef bfbd 0def bfbd 27ef bfbd 3def bfbd
3aef bfbd 1a26 efbf bdef bfbd 3d72 efbf
bd2a 0a02 19ef bfbd 1aef bfbd efbf bd5d
0474 07ef bfbd 45ef bfbd 6eef bfbd efbf
bdef bfbd efbf bdef bfbd efbf bdef bfbd
3146 efbf bd0e efbf bd40 efbf bdef bfbd
efbf bdef bfbd 7cef bfbd efbf bd14 0866
efbf bd6d efbf bd60 efbf bd24 d891 efbf
bd40 645b 4251 1124 285b 553c 2b28 efbf
bdef bfbd 4050 efbf bd35 1eef bfbd 60ef
```

and so on

And when opened in vi

```
wOF2^@^A^@^@^@^A-h^@^M^@^@^@^B��^@^A-^N^@^D^A�^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@?FFTM^\^Z ^F`^@�r^Q^H
��(��X^A6^B$^C�p^K�^P^@^D ^E�^F^G�u[R   rGa���*�^M�'�=�:�^Z&��=r�*
```

I have `spring-boot-starter-security` enabled with the following in the WebSecurity file

```
    @Override
    public void configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(
            "/asset-manifest.json",
            "/favicon.ico",
            "/index.html",
            "/service-worker.js",
            "/static/**"
        );
    }
```

Can anyone identify what could be modifying the fonts?

Comment: Have you tried opening the downloaded file with a text editor to see what it contains?

Comment: added file contents to question

Comment: @Pram issue resolved ?

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor No, never did find a solution